# Wacom in a browser cancels movement

Tags: javascript, canvas, wacom

I am currently trying to use my wacom intous to paint something on a canvas in my browser.

The code is pretty basic and does nothing other than finding the position of my mouse and drawing a path when the mouse is clicked.

This works as expected when I use my mouse. When I use my wacom tablet, the move will be canceled after ~20px and the `lostpointercapture` event as well as the `pointercancel` event will be fired.

This is the code:

```
(function() {


var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var currentPosition = { 
    x: 0, 
    y: 0 
  };

  function init() {
    adjustCanvasSize();
  }

  function adjustCanvasSize() {
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

  function setPosition(ev) {
    currentPosition.x = ev.clientX;
    currentPosition.y = ev.clientY;
  }

  function draw(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (ev.buttons !== 1) {
      return;
    }
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.lineWidth = 1; 
    ctx.lineCap = 'round'; 
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#1a1b1c'; 
    ctx.moveTo(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y); 
    setPosition(ev);
    ctx.lineTo(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y);
    ctx.stroke(); 
  }

  document.addEventListener('pointermove', draw);
  document.addEventListener('pointerdown', setPosition);
  document.addEventListener('pointerenter', setPosition);

  init();
})();
```

Does anyone have an idea why the wacom stops drawing after a few pixel?

Comment: does it work well in any desktop application(e.g. MS Paint or similar)?

Comment: Please do post the [mcve] directly in the question instead of as an external link. If the code is too big, you can only post the relevant parts and leave the link for further reference.

Comment: @skyboyer Yes without any problems

Comment: have you tried different browsers? also try passive event listeners since it [has worked](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/1199) for one drag-n-drop handling library with similar case

Comment: @skyboyer I've tried a few "online paints" and all work well with my wacom tablet. I think I have to do more research...feels like the tablet tries to scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this exact issue, with the "lostpointercapture" PointerEvent after a few pixels traversed

https://jsfiddle.net/mr1z7qg3/

The solution is to add the

```
touch-action: none;
```

style to the location getting drawn on, otherwise the browser will interpret it as a pan/zoom touch gesture https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

...On Chrome

Firefox requires dom.w3c_pointer_events.dispatch_by_pointer_messages in about:config instead